# Why can't I set the Image Source in WPF app?

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, resources

I'm just learning WPF. I'm using VS 2008. I've added an Image control to my XAML, and I added a GIF file to the project.  If I use the XAML Designer's property panel to set the image's Source property, the drop-down list for the Source property contains the following:

C:\Sample Project;component/pinHorizontal.gif

There are several problems with this:

1. My project, named "Sample Project," is not in the root of my drive.
2. Why is ";component" in there?

If I select this value as given, I get the error "Property value is not valid" (yeah, no kidding).

If I go into the XAML source and set the Source property manually, like so:

```
<Image Name="PinImage" Source="pinHorizontal.gif"/>
```

The XAML Designer gives me this error:

"The file pinHorizontal.gif is not part of the project or its 'Build Action' property is not set to 'Resource'."

Why is this task so difficult? How do I assign an image source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a read through [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) - though be warned it's not particularly light reading :-)

I suspect what you want for your image path is `pack://application:,,,/pinHorizontal.gif`.  if your image is set to a `BuildAction` of `Resource`, this will work fine.

Comment: The WPF is undoubtedly powerful and productive -- but why did they have to make so many of its conventions and syntaxes so complex?

Comment: With great power comes great confusion ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Updated to point to a specific (older) .NET framework version so that the link works again.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the image file(pinHorizontal.gif) in the SolutionExplorer, Go to properties, here is the 'Build Action' property, you need to set it to 'Resource'. Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

This post is an "and also"... not an answer to the original question.

I just thought I'd document it in case some other poor booger has this problem in future... and googling that error message finds this SO question... so here's a good place to do so.

I've been creating new icons (actually bitmaps) and adding them "on the fly" to my Visual Studio 2008 project (i.e. Add ~ Existing item). The IDE has been reporting `file ${filename} is not part of the project or its 'Build Action' property is not set to 'Resource'` errors on my XAML page... but my project builds and runs OK... so what gives???

I tried everything I could think of the get visual studio to refresh it's view of the filesystem, to no avail.

Well, I've just dicovered that restarting Visual Studio "refeshes" its cache of filesystem/build-output contents, which makes those annoying non-errors in the IDE go away. So I add a batch of icons, mark them all as Resources ~ Copy if newer, build, and then restart the IDE, and it's all good.

Cheers all. Keith.

Answer (score 0):

In the Solution Explorer, select your project and right click **rebuild the solution**, and try to add the image again, it should work fine.

--or--

under the **Build** tab select **rebuild the solution**, and try to add the image again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code in the XAML to load an image from the absolute path without setting nothing. Use DecodePixelWidth or DecodePixelHeight to save application memory.

```
<Image>
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="200" UriSource="C:\image.png" />
        </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

I was having the exact same problem. I just manually typed in the location of the file when the Choose image box pops up and that worked for me.

I opened the Choose image box again after I got it to work and noticed that `file:///` was now in front of the file location. I know next to nothing about Visual Basic (which is what I'm using) so there may be a good explanation for this, but I don't have it.